# local variable 'account_created' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write usernames and passwords from one file to another based on if account created is true.

```
def main():
    os.system('clear')
    #run account generator for each user in list
    created = open(createdUserNamePasswordFile, 'w')
    creds = [cred.strip() for cred in open(userNamePasswordFile, 'r').readlines()]
    for cred in creds:
        username, password = cred.split(':')
        print('[+] creating account for %s with password %s' % (username,password))
        account_created = create_account(username, password)
    if account_created:
            print('[+] writing name:password to created names...')
            created.write(username + ':' + password + '\n')
            print('[+] deleting name:password from original file...')
            lines = [line.strip() for line in open(userNamePasswordFile, 'r').readlines()]
            f = open(userNamePasswordFile, 'w')
            for line in lines:
                if (line != cred):
                    f.write(line + "\n")
            f.close()
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system('clear')

    created.close()

    
main()
```

username and password are both pulled from a text file

Every time I ran the program though I got the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'account_created' referenced before assignment. I tried setting the variable as a global variable at start of the function because I thought it was outside the scope of the variable but it still does not run.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of `account_created` is in the loop, which means that if the loop is empty, the variable won't be assigned a value. Empty foreach loops don't execute if the object they're iterating over is empty. Your error is probably caused because `creds` is empty.